# C# Line is horizontal

Tags: c#, math

I need a formula to check the angle between the horizontal and a given line and then tell if the given line is horizontal (theta < 45) or vertical (theta > 45) and then return theta.

I know I have to use `Math.Atan` but I don't really know how.
The function signature should be something like

```
double isLineVert(Line line)
{
    // calculate angle //
    return angle; //(in degrees)
}
```

Comment: What is `Line` class, please?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: How about you google `Trigonometry`?

Comment: Line just has basic properties like X1, X2, Y1 and Y2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about basic trigonometry.

Comment: You might learn how to use `Atan` from this simple question + answer: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/mathatan-in-c-sharp

Comment: function name assumes that you need only boolean result: ` if Math.Abs(Y1-Y2) > Math.Abs(X1-X2) then  Line is Vertical`

Comment: Thank you @MBo That's the most trivial solution. It's much more simple than using angles.

Comment: @Damian  If it is valid answer, I would transform comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the approach proposed by @MBo taking the difference in height and length. Here is the function:

```
public static bool? isLineVertical(Line line)
{
    double xDiff = Math.Abs(line.X2 - line.X1);
    double yDiff = Math.Abs(line.Y2 - line.Y1);
    bool? vertical = null;
    if (yDiff > xDiff)
    {
        vertical = true;
    }
    else if (xDiff > yDiff)
    {
        vertical = false;
    }
    return vertical;
}
```